# Updating a shown Dialog

Tags: android, dialog

I created a `Dialog`, using a custom layout:

```
public class WaitDialog extends DialogFragment {
    [..]
    @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        View viewDlg = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_finish, null);
        tvStatusMain = (TextView) viewDlg.findViewById(R.id.tvStatusMain);
        [..]
    }
    public void setMessage(String message) {
        tvStatusMain.setText(message);
    }
}
```

This code, works fine, but when I instantiate the `Dialog` like this:

```
flexWaitDialog = new WaitDialog();
flexWaitDialog.setCancelable(false);
flexWaitDialog.show(this.getFragmentManager(), "login");
```

and then try to update the message:

```
flexWaitDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.initialising));
```

it shows me the default string from the layout. However, when I use a `Handler`:

```
new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        flexWaitDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.initialising));
    }
});
```

it does work. Is there a reason for this hoop-jumping? And if not, is there a better way?

Comment: question is unclear ... where you are trying to call `flexWaitDialog.setMessage` ? in some loop on the UI thread?

Comment: @Selvin in `onResume`, the `setMessage` is directly after the `show` call, inside the `onResume` method.

Comment: could you check what appears first: `setMessage` or `onCreateDialog` ? ... I'm pretty sure that `setMessage`  but then you should get NPE ...

Comment: @Selvin you are right. `setMessage` is called before `onCreateDialog`

Comment: little exp. why: onResume is called on UI thread .... UI thread use message queue ... underlay DialogFragment.show post some code to the UI queue (like createing the dialog itself) ... the code "waits" to be done **after** you go out from onResume ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, `onResume` is called before `onCreateDialog`.

You can modify your class to handle that:

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
            View viewDlg = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_finish, null);
            tvStatusMain = (TextView) viewDlg.findViewById(R.id.tvStatusMain);
            if (mMessage != null) {
                tvStatusMain.seText(mMessage);
            }
            mViewCreated = true;
            [..]
        }

        public void setMessage(String message) {
            if (mViewCreated) {
                tvStatusMain.setText(message);
            } else {
                mMessage = message
            }           
        }
```